# PDF en MVC con datos SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, mvc, pdf

Tengo un problema particular, estoy trabajando con MVC en C# y SQL Server. La idea es que en la pantalla principal se vea un TextBox y un Botón, entonces ingresando un número eso nos traiga nuestros datos. Al traer esos datos la persona puede elegir si quiere ver si esos datos en un PDF. Pero, cuando intento llevar esos datos al pdf surge el problema que mostraré.

Index:

```
<div>
        <form method="post" action="/Home/ChRoja">
            <p>Titulo: <input type="text" name="titulo" /></p>

            <p><input type="submit" value="Chequera Roja" /></p>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Controlador:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult ChRoja() {
            ConexionSQL cn = new ConexionSQL();
            double titulo = Convert.ToDouble(Request.Form["titulo"].ToString());
            return View(cn.cargarDatos(titulo));
        }

        public ActionResult Pdf()
        {
            double titulo = Convert.ToDouble(Request.Form["id"].ToString());
            return new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf("ChRoja", titulo);
        }
```

ChRoja:

```
    <body style='background: url(/images/CHEQUERAS-ROJAS-CORTA.png) no-repeat center'>
    <div>
        <form id="form">

            <div>
                <table back>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>

                            <th scope="row" abbr="Suscriptor">Suscriptor: </th>
                            <td>

                                <b>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Apellido) @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nombre)</b>
                            </td>
                            <td>Título: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Titulo)</td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.ActionLink("Ver detalles en PDF", "Pdf", new { id = item.Titulo })
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </table>
            </div>
        </form>

        <a href="@Url.Action("Pdf", "Home")">Convertir a Pdf</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

El Error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna idea de como solucionarlo?

Comment: En ningún lado estás enviando ese `Request.Form["id"]`

Comment: ¿Y cómo lo envío? Porque a mi entender, y desde mi ignorancia, pensé que el error era que no estaba tomando el parámetro de ["id"]

Comment: Por lo que veo en tu código, estás iniciando en ASP.net MVC, toma https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY es un resumen de un curso de varias horas que llevé años atrás en la Microsoft Virtual Academy.

Comment: por otro lado, si no cierras la conexión, tendrás problemas con la base de datos

Comment: Un detalle más, cuando pongas Rotativa en producción, verifica si tienes errores de network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te hace falta determinar el id en el parámetro:

```
public ActionResult Pdf(string id)
    {
        double titulo = Convert.ToDouble(id);
        return new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf("ChRoja", titulo);
    }
```

Comment: Pues agregué ese parámetro y sigue saliendo el mismo error

Comment: Acabo de modificar la respuesta, revisa

Comment: Ahora sale el mismo error pero en el `ActionResult ChRoja()`

Comment: intenta, creo que ya tienes todos los elementos necesarios para analizar y tomar acción, si más tarde sigues sin respuesta, colocaré lo que haga falta :)

Comment: Pues seguí sin respuesta ya que lo que creo que necesito es pasar el parámetro que tengo en la consulta al pdf

Comment: ¿Intentaste algo?

Comment: intenté tipo mostrar el valor del parámetro, en este caso título sería el parámetro, y usarlo para cargar el pdf. Pero, no ha funcionado muy bien que digamos

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega lo que has intentado con los nuevos errores que hayas experimentado, aquí en el sitio se valora mucho cuando un usuario intenta darle solución gracias a los comentarios y respuestas :D

Comment: Pues he dado con que he cambiado todo el código, así que si pudieras ayudarme te lo agradecería. He hecho una nueva pregunta

Answer (score 1):

tienes que validar el parámetro de entrada ya que lo estas buscando en el `querystring`, si este llega vacío el `string` esta definido como nulo

si le verificar el valor el `Request.Form["id"].ToString()` debe ser nulo

agregale un `if` para validarlo. no es un problema de sql server es de tu mvc

Comment: Pensé que el problema era que no estaba tomando el valor de la consulta y por eso el error